# Flexslider controlNav not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, navigation, slider, controls, flexslider

Flexslider controlNav not working in Firefox browser. In chrome, safari, opera working properly.
I am working on Codeigniter. In wordpress and drupal with using plugin properly working.

Comment: On their website it works in Firefox so it is maybe an error of your code or something. So are you going to share your code?

Comment: Give me the link of their website. i am checking all felxslider demo dosen't work controlNav pagintion
Link which i am checking:
http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Comment: So how/where did you get the plugin?


http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Comment: i not using any plugin. and check controllNav of this link webpage  flexslider.woothemes.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just use this jquery instand of your jquery.flexslider.js**

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Hussy/86yLmL43/2/
```

Comment: Many changes on jquery.flexslider.js so better to you replace with this file

Comment: The link seems broken.